# Фильтрация данных из таблицы по массивам?

Tags: filter, база-данных, php, sql, mysql

Есть таблица:

```
articles. id   | author                | title     | content  | type
             1 | author1, author2      | thetitle1 | text1    | typeA
             2 | author1               | thetitle2 | text2    | typeB
             3 | author2               | thetitle3 | text3    | typeA
```

С клиента приходят массивы, они являются как бы фильтрами данных:

```
$conditions = array();
$where = '';

if(isset($_POST['authors'])){ //empty, is_array and etc.
  $authors = $_POST['authors']; // [ author1, author2 ]
  $conditions[] = "author IN ('".implode("','",$authors)."')";
}
if(isset($_POST['types'])){
  $types = $_POST['types']; // [ typeA, typeB ]
  $conditions[] = "type IN ('".implode("','",$types)."')";
}

if(!empty($conditions)){
  $where = ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles".$where;
```

Все бы ничего, да вот только поле `author` может содержать авторов через запятую, как видно из примера, что не подпадает под такой фильтр: `author IN ('author1')` - естественно такой фильтр выберет только 2-ую запись из таблицы, а нужно все записи где этот автор участвовал ( а это 1-ая и 2-ая записи ).

Comment: скажу сразу что структуру таблиц(ы) не я придумывал и переделывать, добавлять еще таблицы не хочется. Вот как есть, так есть.

Answer (score 2):

Сходу приходит на ум такой вариант:

```
if(isset($_POST['authors'])){ //empty, is_array and etc.
  $authors = $_POST['authors']; // [ author1, author2 ]
  if (is_string($authors)) 
    $authors = array($authors);
  if (is_array($authors)) {
    foreach ($authors as $value)
    {
      $conditions[] = "FIND_IN_SET('".$value."',  `author`)";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: а это не подразумевает что само поле должно иметь тип `SET`?

Comment: Как-то с этим `AND` не хорошо получается, вышло что-то вроде такого запроса: `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE FIND_IN_SET('author1', `author`) AND FIND_IN_SET('author2', `author`) AND FIND_IN_SET('author3', `author`)`.

Comment: Нет, поле должно быть обычным текстовым - мы просто подставляем его в функцию `FIND_IN_SET` в виде списка вариантов значений, тип данных `SET` тут вообще не причем.

Ну а лаконичный запрос при такой структуре не получится.

Answer (score 1):

При такой структуре, видимо, придется использовать `LIKE` (или `SUBSTRING`) с каждым значением из массива: `author LIKE '%author1%' OR author LIKE '%author2%'` ...

Или значения в столбце преобразовывать в массив и сравнивать массивы.

Comment: `LIKE` с такой структурой никогда не катит.

"a,b,c", "k,ab,ac" - `LIKE %a%` вернет обе, а по условию нужна только первая.

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду, что имя атора является подстрокой в имени другого автора, то согдален. Но это уже зависит от данных, насколько вероятна такая ситуация. Например, если данные типа Фамилия И.О., то маловероятно, я полагаю. А если это логины/ники, то вероятность высока.